# How to pass dictionary values to callback function?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a dict of titles with values representing 3 letter abbreviations.

I have a list of buttons with the titles, and I need the on_click to return the abbreviation.

What I have now returns the titles (button text) but I can't figure out how to pass along the whole dictionary entry, or just the value.

```
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
import citylists
import cat_dict

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

store = JsonStore('data.json')

Builder.load_string("""
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter


<ListViewModal>:
    ListView:
        size_hint: .8, .8
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(
            data=[i for i in root.categories],
            args_converter=lambda row_index, rec: \
            {'text': rec, 'on_press': root.callback, 'size_hint_y': None, 'height': 25},
            cls=ListItemButton)

""")




class ListViewModal(ModalView):
    categories = sorted(cat_dict.SECTION_DICT)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListViewModal, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def callback(self, instance):
        print "HI" + str(instance)


class MainView(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['cols'] = 1
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        listview_modal = ListViewModal()

        self.add_widget(listview_modal)

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


mainscreen=MainScreen()
mainlayout = MainView()
mainscreen.add_widget(mainlayout)

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(mainscreen)

class CARApp(App):

    def build(self):
       return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
     CARApp().run()
```

cat_dict.py

```
EECTION_DICT = {
    "accounting+finance": "acc",
    "admin / office": "ofc",
    "arch / engineering": "egr",
    'art / media / design': 'med',
    'biotech / science': 'sci',
    'business / mgmt': 'bus',
    'customer management': 'csr',
    'education': 'edu',....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you actually have to pass anything to the callback.  It looks like the following does what you want:

```
class ListViewModal(ModalView):
    section_dict = cat_dict.SECTION_DICT
    categories = sorted(section_dict)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListViewModal, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def callback(self, instance):
        print "HI" + str(instance)
        # Print abbreviation from dictionary lookup
        print ListViewModal.section_dict[instance.text]
```

Which outputs:

```
HI<ListItemButton text=accounting+finance>
acc
```

But one way to pass extra arguments to your callback would be to change

```
'on_press': root.callback
# to
'on_press': lambda inst: root.callback(inst, 'some arg')
```

Then change

```
def callback(self, instance):
# to
def callback(self, instance, arg):
```

[The docs](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) also list using `itertools.partial` as an option, in addition to using a lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

```
EECTION_DICT = {
"accounting+finance": "acc",
"admin / office": "ofc",
"arch / engineering": "egr",
'art / media / design': 'med',
'biotech / science': 'sci',
'business / mgmt': 'bus'}

def foo(args):
    for item in args.items():
       print(item)
    
foo(EECTION_DICT)
```

or

```
def foo(**args):
    for key,item in args.items():
        print(key, item)
    
foo(**EECTION_DICT)
```